# How to download about 1000 small files (~20Kb) with the same URL mask using bash

Tags: bash, download, sh, jpeg, wget

There is a certain amount (~1000) of small jpeg files (about 20Kb) that are located at the URLs like:

```
https://example.com/file=1.0
https://example.com/file=1.1
...
https://example.com/file=1.973
https://example.com/file=1.974
```

How to download them using bash script? I do not know how to write scripts, but I think that there is some simple way using wget for example.
They have the same `filename.jpeg` so need to download them with consecutive names like `filename-1.jpg`, `filename-2.jpg` ...

Comment: I replaced the `script` tag by the `sh` tag, because the `script` tag shall not be used as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script

Answer (score 2):

Curl has this built-in feature to be able to download multiple URLs with generated sequences and apply those same sequences to the saved file name:

```bash
curl \
  --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36' \
  --parallel \
  --url "https://example.com/file=1.[0-974]" \
  --output "filename-#1.jpg"
```

See: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-o

> **`-o`, `--output <file>`**
>
> Write output to `<file>` instead of stdout. If you are using `{}` or `[]` to fetch multiple documents, you should quote the URL and you can use '`#`' followed by a number in the `<file>` specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current string for the URL being fetched. Like in:
>
> ```
>  curl "http://{one,two}.example.com" -o "file_#1.txt"
> ```
>
> or use several variables like:
>
> ```
>  curl "http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com" -o "#1_#2"
> ```
>
> You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have. For example, if you specify two URLs on the same command line, you can use it like this:
>
> ```
>   curl -o aa example.com -o bb example.net
> ```
>
> and the order of the -o options and the URLs does not matter, just that the first -o is for the first URL and so on, so the above command line can also be written as
>
> ```
>   curl example.com example.net -o aa -o bb
> ```
>
> See also the [`--create-dirs`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--create-dirs) option to create the local directories dynamically. Specifying the output as '`-`' (a single dash) will force the output to be done to stdout.
>
> To suppress response bodies, you can redirect output to `/dev/null`:
>
> ```
>   curl example.com -o /dev/null
> ```
>
> Or for Windows use `nul`:
>
> ```
>   curl example.com -o nul
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> curl -o file https://example.com
> curl "http://{one,two}.example.com" -o "file_#1.txt"
> curl "http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com" -o "#1_#2"
> curl -o file https://example.com -o file2 https://example.net
> ```
>
> See also [-O, --remote-name](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-O), [--remote-name-all](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--remote-name-all) and [-J, --remote-header-name](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-J).

Comment: Thank you very much! But it seems I found a new problem, the website server does not allow to download anything via curl or wget, it returns 403 :( I'm not sure if there is a way to get around this, I'll look for ways to solve it

Comment: @Vleg.sh You may need Curl to advertise itself as a regular user agent (browser). See: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-A Like: `curl --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36' --parallel "https://example.com/file=1.[0-974]" --output "filename-#1.jpg"`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried, with the user agent from your example, as well as from my browser, server still returns 403. Apparently it's not so easy to deceive him. But now he supplements the page code with some comments at the bottom, which means he reacted to the addition of a user agent.

Comment: @Vleg.sh This confirms that this site has active technical restrictions to prevent harvesting content like this. Sometimes user-agent filtering is broadly set by hosting and can be legitimately by-passed. But here, this site seems to explicitly prohibit this kind automated usage. I'd recommend against trying to circumvent it. See if they have a public Web service API instead, to download your files legitimately without front-running their website.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: An improved version of the below would be (thanks to the comments):

```
for i in {0..974}; do wget https://example.com/file=1."$i"; done;
```

(The quotes might not be required in this particular case as there are only numeric values, but it's good to adhere to best practices.)

You can use `for` with `seq` like this:

```
for i in `seq 0 974`; do wget https://example.com/file=1.$i; done;
```

Comment: `seq` is non-standard tool and back-ticks are obsolete outdated deprecated syntax that has been replaced by `$()` some 25 years ago.

Comment: Missing quotes is also a potential issue.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find common problems like these.

Comment: `for i in {0..974}`